# How to make a for loop input data within a while loop until a patient's name is reached

Tags: c++

Input file that has the name, some number, another number, then an identification number, followed by a cost:

```
Jennifer Jones
145634
2
EX1 50.00
BD1 25.00
Paul Peters
173409
4
EX2 75.00
BD2 120.00
XR1 250.00
EQ1  50.00
```

The code I have so far:

```
    //Input the patient's name from the input file
    getline(fin, patientName);

    //while there is data in the input file
    while (fin)
    {
        //Initial Processing for a Patient---------------------------------------------------------

        //Input the patient's id & the number of services from the input file
        fin >> patientIdentificationNumber >> numberOfServices;

        //Output the divider to the output file
        fout << setfill('*') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << ' ' << setfill(' ') << endl;

        //Output the patient's name, patient's id number & the number of services to the output file
        fout << "Patient Name: " << patientName << endl
            << "Patient's ID Number: " << patientIdentificationNumber << endl
            << "Number Of Services: " << numberOfServices << endl;

        //Output the divider to the output file
        fout << setfill('*') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << ' ' << setfill(' ') << endl;

        //Output a blank line to the output file
        fout << endl;

        //Output the heading for the service id & cost to the output file
        fout << left << setw(20) << "Service ID"
            << right << setw(20) << "Cost" << endl;

        //Output the divider to the output file
        fout << setfill('*') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << ' ' << setfill(' ') << endl;

        //
        //Initialize the patient's total bill
        patientTotalBill = 0;

        //Patient Processing-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        //for 
        for()
        {
        //Input 
        //     
        //      

        //Output the service id & the cost of the service to the output file
        fout << left << setw(20) << serviceIdentifcation
            << right << setw(20) << serviceCost << endl;

        //end for
        }
```

How do I make the for loop work? It has to be in this setup with the while loop and for loop inside of it.

Comment: Hi yuidk, thanks for asking your question! Please be aware that the minimum character requirements are there for a reason; if your post is not long enough, try to explain more about your code rather than just adding random sentences. What have you tried so far? Is there any further context that will help us answer? Things like this will help you get better and quicker answers.

Comment: `while(fin)` is wrong. Using `fin` in a boolean context will not tell you if the next reads are going too succeed. How could it?  It doesn't know how much and what kind of data you will be trying to read. It only knows about the last reads and tells you if any of those failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read `numberOfServices` times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfServices; ++i) {
    fin >> serviceName >> serviceCost;
    // do whatever you want with the info.
}
```

Comment: thank you so much I feel very stupid right now

Comment: @yuidk please don't, we all miss obvious things from time to time. :-)